# How to create a PySpark wheel from PyPi package download as tar.gz

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone let me know how to create a wheel (.whl) from a PySpark package downloaded as
pyspark-3.4.0.tar.gz from PyPi.

Alternatively, can someone let me if there already is a pyspark.whl file already available?

Comment: Mind if I asked why would you do it?

Comment: Hi @JacekLaskowski, thanks for getting in touch. I did it because I wanted to import PySpark as wheel in SnowFlake. I successfully created the wheel, but it wasn't necessary. I was going to delete this question. But thanks for reaching out

Comment: Can you answer your question with the steps? I myself would not know how to do it 